# An Error Was Encountered Unable to locate the model you have specified: user

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I set DB password on application/config/database.php, then showing me an error message.

> An Error Was Encountered  Unable to locate the model you have
>   specified: user

If not set password, its showing me:

> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 346

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'masudtools_auto';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'masudtools_post';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre']= '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

/*USER DB*/
$db['second']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['second']['username'] = 'masudtools_auto';
$db['second']['password'] = 'password';
$db['second']['database'] = 'masudtools_post';
$db['second']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['second']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['second']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['second']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['second']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['second']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['second']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['second']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['second']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['second']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['second']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Make sure your filename and class name has only first letter upper case as explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming also I would name your models like `User_model.php` and `class User_model extends CI_Model {}` that way if any controllers same name as model wont be any conflict.

Comment: When you get this kind of error, the error isnt in the core/Loader.php. Your model name might not be capitalized, or your model and the Class name are not the same

Answer (score -1):

What is meant by model here? is it CI model or any other, if it is CI model check weather you have extended it with CI_Model and relevant databases are loaded to model

Comment: are you using and model classes here

Comment: yes, i'm using on User.php,mod_post.php,mod_general.php,mod_form.php

Comment: have you loaded $this->load->database() something in your model , and extended the ci base model class

Comment: class User extends CI_Model{

Comment: no, but i have this $this->db->insert($table, $data);  return $this->db->insert_id();

Comment: you shuold load the database driver and extend the CI_Model in your model class

Comment: class User extends CI_Model
{
    
    function __construct() {
        
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function insert($table, $data) {
        
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);
        
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

Comment: have you loaded database library in autoload.php in config folder

Comment: if not you have to load the particular database before doing any transaction

Comment: This code: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');

Comment: try $this->load->database("second",TRUE); and $second->get("tabelname")